# How to add item to dynamodb if a field does not exist or matches a condition?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I want to save an item if a field, is either non-existent or less than a given value.

So the first time the item is written, the field would be non-existent. and on subsequent writes, it needs to be less than a given value.

However it seems `DynamoDBSaveExpression` does not allow multiple conditions on a column. My current code looks like this:

```
Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expected = new HashMap<>();
expected.put("lastProcessTime", new ExpectedAttributeValue().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LT).withValue(
                new AttributeValue().withN(String.valueOf(processTime))
        ));
DynamoDBSaveExpression saveExpression = new DynamoDBSaveExpression()
                .withExpected(expected);
dynamoDBMapper.save(item, saveExpression);
```

However, this does not work if there isnt an existing item in the table with the same primary key since in that case the value of `lastProcessTime` is `null`.

How do i achieve what i need here?